# Array of structs not retaining value

Tags: c

Im trying to to fill a 3d array with a bunch of string tokens , this seems to work perfectly fine - and my code produces expected output:

```
0:0:0 : ADD
0:0:1 : 4
0:1:0 : MOV
0:1:1 : ACC
0:1:2 : RIGHT
0:2:0 : SAV
1:0:0 : ADD
1:0:1 : 4
1:1:0 : MOV
1:1:1 : ACC
1:1:2 : RIGHT
1:2:0 : SAV
2:0:0 : ADD
2:0:1 : 4
2:1:0 : MOV
2:1:1 : ACC
2:1:2 : RIGHT
2:2:0 : SAV
```

However - whenever I try to access/ print the array from any other location I get completely different output like:

```
SAV

(null)
SAV
SAV

RIGHT
SAV
SAV
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
SAV

(null)
SAV
SAV

RIGHT
SAV
SAV
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
SAV

(null)
SAV
SAV

RIGHT
SAV
SAV
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

I am aware that i will get a few NULL - however thats not the issue , the problem is that there are tokens missing.
Here is the code I am working with - I have left comments in the releveant sections.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>



struct node {
    int waitState;
    int acc;
    int sec;
    int pc;
    
    char * memPool[12][3];
    char * currentInstruction;
}
node0, node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, node6, node7, node8, node9, node10, node11;

int nth, j, x;

int Z = -1;
int Y = -1;
int X = -1;

int main() {
    
    struct node nodeSet[12] = {
        node0,
        node1,
        node2,
        node3,
        node4,
        node5,
        node6,
        node7,
        node8,
        node9,
        node10,
        node11
    };
    char* aCouple[3] = {"SWP","SAV","NEG"};
    char* hCouple[8] = {"ADD","SUB","JMP","JGZ","JLZ","JEZ","JRO","JNZ"} ;
    char* pCouple[1]= {"MOV"};
    int lineCount;
    FILE * saveFile = fopen("save/save.txt", "r");
    if (saveFile == NULL) {
        perror("Savefile missing!"); //sdl needs to handle this.
        return 1;
    }
    char lineBuffer[128];
    while (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof(lineBuffer), saveFile) != NULL) {
        lineCount++;
        for (nth = 0; lineBuffer[nth] == ' ' || lineBuffer[nth] == '\t'; nth++);
        for (j = 0; lineBuffer[nth]; nth++) {
            lineBuffer[j++] = lineBuffer[nth];
        }
        lineBuffer[j] = '\0';
        for (nth = 0; lineBuffer[nth] != '\0'; nth++) {
            if (lineBuffer[nth] != ' ' && lineBuffer[nth] != '\t')
                j = nth;
        }
        lineBuffer[j + 1] = '\0';
        char * instruction[lineCount];
        instruction[x] = lineBuffer;

        char * zDelim[60];
        char * xDelim[60];
        int a = 0, b = 0;
        zDelim[a] = strtok(instruction[x], "\n");
        while (zDelim[a] != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(zDelim[a], "@") == 0) {
                Z++;
                Y = -1;
            } else {
                Y++;
                X = -1;
                xDelim[b] = strtok(zDelim[a], " ");
                while (xDelim[b] != NULL) {
                    X++;
                    if(X > 2) {
                        printf("BUFFER OVERFLOW! -> %s can not be assembled",xDelim[b]);
                        return 1;            
                    }
                    nodeSet[Z].memPool[Y][X] = xDelim[b];
                    xDelim[b] = strtok(NULL, " ");
            //        printf("%u:%u:%u : %s\n", Z, Y, X, nodeSet[Z].memPool[Y][X]);
                }
            }
            zDelim[++a] = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }
        x++;
   
    } 
// second attempt to print - which produces incorrect output.
    int i,o,u;
    for(i = 0; i<= 2; i++){
        for(o = 0; o <= 3; o++){
            for(u = 0; u<=3; u++ ){
                printf("%s\n", nodeSet[i].memPool[o][u]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*whenever I try to access/ print the array from any other location*". What exactly does "other location" mean? What are the two locations you are referring to? Seems there is only one `printf` in the code that prints the values.

Comment: Your code would be easier to debug and understand if you break it up into functions that perform different parts of the task. Also note that the initialisation `struct node nodeSet[12] = {` is pointless. It's just making a copy of 12 nodes with zero values. May as well just `memset` the whole array to 0.

Comment: @kaylum , "What exactly does "other location" mean?" - it means , if I try to print the array , from any other point in the code - other than where the first print statement occurs , i get incorrect output , irrespective of where i put the other print statement - hence why i did not include one

Comment: Then show the actual code that produces wrong output. Details matter so it is always best to show the exact code even if you think it's not important (by definition you don't know where the problem is). Also include the exact input, expected result and actual result. See: [mre].

Comment: @kaylum okay - will do

Comment: You are putting pointers into the same `lineBuffer` for all structs. That `linebuffer` content changes on each iteration as it is overwritten by `fgets`. So the data is only valid for one iteration (as your test results exactly show). One solution is to `strdup` each of the strings.

Comment: @kaylum , but isnt that what I would want? thats not really the issue...